# should thread sleep in loop on multi core system

Tags: multithreading, sleep, scheduling

If there are multiple threads running in one process, should each thread sleep for some time in its loop to make sure other threads get cpu time to run provided the process in running on a multi core system?

Comment: 1) one process can use multiple cores. 2) Sleeping in a threed pause execution of tge thread, not force another thread to run. The fact that other thread run at that moment is just optimisation, not the goal of sleeping. So you will never be sure. Can you exact your question to be more clear?

Comment: well, say I have three threads in a process, each thread has a infinite loop to run, is it possible that one thread runs all the time but the other two got no chance to run.

Comment: In general this depends on hardware, operating system, scheduler algorithm, scheduler algorithm implementation and perhaps some luck. But you definitely can't guarantee such properties if you will sleep in the thread. I guess, if you take modern PC OS, then if your threads do similar job, they will get approximately fair amount of cpu time.